App crashes on Oppo A52 and A17 with Android 11 and 12
I develop Enterprise Mobile apps for the aged care sector on Xamarin forms. On Oppo A52 and A17 (CPH2477) running Android 11 and 12 the app will crash. On the logon screen where there is no activity it tends to crash consistently after 15 to 18 seconds. When a fresh install is made this does not happen but when I close the app and start it again it will.
I have tried removing animation SDK linking. Our company wants our app to work on all devices and not have to force clients to buy other hardware. The app uses SQLite and httpclient and reads and writes to external/internal storage. There was a change to storage permissions over Android 11 so I have added these permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
Targets Android 13.
Minimum Android 7.1

On an Oppo A78 running Android 13 the app runs with no problem. All other mobile devices of other brands have no issue either. Oppo versions running Android 7.1 do not have any issue. What issues do these devices have and how to program against them?
The log cat:
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
07-01 14:57:56.275  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17538392, now = 17538443
07-01 14:57:56.174  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17538289, now = 17538342
07-01 14:57:56.072  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17538188, now = 17538239
07-01 14:57:56.041  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   5301    HoraeHelper getAllShellTemps tSize : 4
07-01 14:57:55.969  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17538087, now = 17538137
07-01 14:57:55.867  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537987, now = 17538035
07-01 14:57:55.766  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537883, now = 17537934
07-01 14:57:55.670  OPPO CPH2069    Info    5174    Athena  MemoryGuardAction: triggerMemory:1500MB, availMemory:1508MB
07-01 14:57:55.668  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   3817    Launcher.   panicValue = false
07-01 14:57:55.666  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    AS.AudioService getParameters() keyValuePairs:OPLUS_AUDIO_GET_FOCUS_STACK
07-01 14:57:55.429  OPPO CPH2069    Error   3817    Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView    mForceHideDot is false
07-01 14:57:55.428  OPPO CPH2069    Info    3817    chatty  uid=10113(com.oppo.launcher) identical 2 lines
07-01 14:57:55.664  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537782, now = 17537833
07-01 14:57:55.562  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537680, now = 17537730
07-01 14:57:55.460  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537577, now = 17537628
07-01 14:57:55.428  OPPO CPH2069    Error   3817    Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView    mForceHideDot is false
07-01 14:57:55.394  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceManager  unBindUpdateService true
07-01 14:57:55.389  OPPO CPH2069    Warning 8669    ClockTag ClockWidget.ClockWidgetManager updateWeatherInfo -- weatherEntity is null!
07-01 14:57:55.387  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceVersionUtils serviceVersionCode14006006
07-01 14:57:55.387  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    chatty  uid=10197(com.coloros.alarmclock) pool-2-thread-6 identical 1 line
07-01 14:57:55.387  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceVersionUtils serviceVersionCode14006006
07-01 14:57:55.386  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherBaseDataTask    after doRequestFromWeatherService getLocationCityDataAndUpdateWeatherInfoIfNeeded result true
07-01 14:57:55.381  OPPO CPH2069    Error   24146   WeatherS_LocalUtils startAutoGetLocalCity has no locate city
 thread: Thread[pool-2-thread-7,5,main]
07-01 14:57:55.379  OPPO CPH2069    Error   24146   WeatherS_LocalUtils startAutoGetLocalCity bg location permission:false
07-01 14:57:55.375  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceManager  unBindUpdateService true
07-01 14:57:55.375  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherBaseDataTask    after doRequestFromWeatherService getResidentSecureSettingsData result true
07-01 14:57:55.367  OPPO CPH2069    Error   24146   WeatherS_WeatherCommonServiceProxy  getLocationCityInfo
07-01 14:57:55.357  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537474, now = 17537525
07-01 14:57:55.355  OPPO CPH2069    Warning 3837    [0]DCS-MobileHelper getContryCode slotid=1,type=1,code=null,result=
07-01 14:57:55.354  OPPO CPH2069    Warning 3837    [0]DCS-MobileHelper getContryCode slotid=0,type=1,code=null,result=
07-01 14:57:55.346  OPPO CPH2069    Warning 3837    [0]DCS-MobileHelper getContryCode slotid=1,type=1,code=null,result=
07-01 14:57:55.346  OPPO CPH2069    Warning 3837    [0]DCS-MobileHelper getContryCode slotid=0,type=1,code=null,result=
07-01 14:57:55.315  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherBaseDataTask    executeRequest getResidentSecureSettingsData
07-01 14:57:55.315  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherBaseDataTask    executeRequest getLocationCityDataAndUpdateWeatherInfoIfNeeded
07-01 14:57:55.314  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceManager  onServiceConnected
07-01 14:57:55.313  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceManager  onServiceConnected
07-01 14:57:55.308  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceManager  bindUpdateService false
07-01 14:57:55.308  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherBaseDataTask    Service has not started, bind update Service.
07-01 14:57:55.300  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceManager  bindUpdateService false
07-01 14:57:55.300  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherBaseDataTask    Service has not started, bind update Service.
07-01 14:57:55.294  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceVersionUtils serviceVersionCode14006006
07-01 14:57:55.294  OPPO CPH2069    Info    8669    WeatherS_WeatherServiceVersionUtils serviceVersionCode14006006
07-01 14:57:55.256  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537374, now = 17537425
07-01 14:57:55.155  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537272, now = 17537323
07-01 14:57:55.053  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537170, now = 17537221
07-01 14:57:55.036  OPPO CPH2069    Verbose 1819    OppoBaseWatchdog    @WatchDog_ error e: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /d/wakeup_sources: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-01 14:57:54.952  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17537068, now = 17537119
07-01 14:57:54.849  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17536966, now = 17537017
07-01 14:57:54.747  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17536865, now = 17536915
07-01 14:57:54.645  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17536763, now = 17536814
07-01 14:57:54.544  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17536660, now = 17536712
07-01 14:57:54.441  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17536559, now = 17536610
07-01 14:57:54.340  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   1819    ColorAutomaticBrightnessController  Skip onSensorChanaged, pre time = 17536456, now = 17536508
07-01 14:57:54.307  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   29490   MbnSystemService    MbnTest_ EVENT_SERVICE_BINDED
07-01 14:57:54.307  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   29490   MbnSystemService    MbnTest_ Fail to find MultiMode from Meta Info
07-01 14:57:54.307  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   29490   MbnSystemService    MbnTest_ telMode:dsds mbnId:null
07-01 14:57:54.307  OPPO CPH2069    Warning 29490   QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK QCRIL_EVT_HOOK_GET_CONFIG failed w/ org.codeaurora.telephony.utils.CommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE
07-01 14:57:54.306  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   29490   QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK sendOemRilRequestRaw returns value = -2
07-01 14:57:54.306  OPPO CPH2069    Debug   4253    QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager  handleMessage what = 2
07-01 14:57:54.305  OPPO CPH2069    Error   4253    QcRilRequest    [1159] < OEM_HOOK_RAW error: org.codeaurora.telephony.utils.CommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE
07-01 14:57:54.305  OPPO CPH2069    Info    4253    QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel   [0]processOemHookResponse serial no: 1159 error: 2length=0
07-01 14


do you have any crash reporting tools installed?  Does it always crash at the same page?  Do you have exception handling and logging in that code?

I am using logcat and the log is attached.  It crashes after 15 to 18 seconds of just sitting on the screen. 15 to 18 seconds after fist opening.  I have added crash reports in the app itself to supply a text note on reopen/ run in strict mode but it does not reach these it just pops. I have appcenter crash reporting also and added symbols but does not reach any of these.
What crash reports would you suggest.

Download android system webview device or android system webview beta from google play store and goes to developer mode and change webview provider.
Not working for me now i trying downgrade google chrome browser.
Hope its working in may its working fine i belive the google chrome update get the problem.
Android System WebView device get an update today afternon so its seem so the update fix app crashed not open on Oppo A17 of cuorse i canged Android System WebView from developers settings to Android System WebView Device and update the Android System WebView Device app.
Not seem fix the issue i waiting for a solutios who fix the issue.

I have found the issue.
I work in Xamarin Forms and the Android X upgrade caused an issue on these specific low end oppo devices only.
It seemed to be an issue with the below libraries that I needed to introduce overriding the dependent packages brought in by AndroidX.Core
Upgrade to AndroidX.Core 1.12.0.4 removes kotlin issues but oppo crash issue reappears (higher .Core moves to .Net 6)!!! Downgrade to AndroidX.Core 1.9.0.2 and add Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk7 Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8 v1.8.0.1 instead of accepting transitive packages of lower versions.  e.g. bring into line with Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib 1.8.0.1
